# ¿Como actualizar tabla despues de insertar un dato nuevo?

Tags: java, jtable

Estoy realizando una aplicación de ejemplo en la cual uso datos obtenidos desde la base de datos con **MySQL** a lo cual los muestro en un **jTable** el cual esta en una interfaz **jFrame**.

## En teoría lo que debería suceder es lo siguiente

1. La interfaz(**jFrame**) **GestionEmpleados** carga un **jTable** con los datos de los empleados
2. Se abre interfaz(**jFrame**) **AgregarEmpleado** sin cerrar **GestionEmpleados**
3. Al dar Clic en el **jButton**(Agregar) se cierra **AgregarEmpleado** y se debe actualizar el **jTable** que esta en **GestionEmpleados**

---

Realizo un nuevo registro en la base de datos en otra interfaz igual de tipo jFrame, pero al dar en el boton **agregar** intento lo siguiente.

```
new Conexion().insertEmpleado(nombre, apPaterno, apMaterno,
                        telefono, direccion, puesto, usuario, pass);
                new GestionEmpleados().llenarTabla();
                hide();
```

Pensé que llamando al método que utilizo para llenar la tabla se cargarían los datos nuevo, pero no funciona me muestra los mismos datos que cuando cargo la interfaz
intente las siguientes cosas.

1. Eliminar todas las filas y cargar de nuevo
2. Intente el método `fireTableDataChanged();`
3. Intente con el metodo `removeAll()` pensando que limpiaria la tabla y cargar de nuevo todo.

Entre otras cosas de tantas que fueron que no me acuerdo

Mi método para llenar la tabla es el siguiente que se encuentra mi **jFrame** `GestionEmpleados` el cual me interesa que siempre se mantenga abierto.

```
public void llenarTabla() {
    Object[] data = new Object[6];
    DefaultTableModel tablaEmpleados = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
    ArrayList<Empleado> lista = new Conexion().getEmpleados();
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        data[0] = lista.get(i).getNombre();
        data[1] = lista.get(i).getApellidoPaterno();
        data[2] = lista.get(i).getApellidoMaterno();
        data[3] = lista.get(i).getTelefono();
        data[4] = lista.get(i).getDireccion();
        data[5] = lista.get(i).getPuestoEmpleado();
        tablaEmpleados.addRow(data);
    }
    jTableEmpleados.setModel(tablaEmpleados);
}
```

El constructor de la clase es el siguiente

```
public GestionEmpleados() {
        initComponents();
        llenarTabla();
    }
```

El metodo main es el siguiente

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GestionEmpleados.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GestionEmpleados.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GestionEmpleados.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GestionEmpleados.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GestionEmpleados().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: ¿ya revisaste que el método Conexion().getEmpleados() te esté dando los empleados ya con el que agregaste?  Te pregunto porque primero habría que identificar si el problema es de la base de datos o del modelo de la JTable.

Comment: @AlbertoLopez Acabo de realizar pruebas y si cuando carga me trae la consulta ya me trae los nuevos registros revisare que se agregue al arreglo.

Comment: @AlbertoLopez Incluso revise si el arreglo se lleno con los nuevos datos ingreso un dato nuevo y muestro los datos antes y despues de realizar el registro. para lo cual el registro nuevo si aparece en la lista.. por lo tanto si deberia actualizar la tabla.

Comment: ya vi el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de tu clase GestionEmpleados agregar :

```
  private static GestionEmpleados gestionEmpleados;

  public GestionEmpleados() {
      initComponents();
      llenarTabla();
      gestionEmpleados = this; //agregar esto en el constructor.
  }

/*
 Agregamos método estático que puede ser llamado desde fuera
*/
public static void actualizaTabla() {
     if (gestionEmpleados != null) {
        gestionEmpleados.llenaTabla();
     }
}
```

Dentro de AgregarEmpleado modificar el método donde insertas empleados, para que accese al método estático:

```
new Conexion().insertEmpleado(nombre, apPaterno, apMaterno,
                    telefono, direccion, puesto, usuario, pass);
            GestionEmpleados.actualizaTabla();
            hide();
```

Comment: Si eso no resuelve, favor de poner el método(s) de como cargas la interfaz

Comment: Intente colocando el Object dentro del método `llenarTabla()` pero no funciono, coloque mas información en la pregunta, no se si es lo que pediste ya que si coloco el metodo `initComponents();` seria bastante extenso.

Comment: Creo que también seria importante mencionar que el proyecto se realiza con Netbeans

Comment: ya modifiqué la respuesta. Avísame si algo no entiendes de lo que puse. Estabas creando un JFrame GestionEmpleados, pero no lo estabas mostrando, supongo estabas viendo el que habías creado con el main.

Comment: Mil disculpas creo que formule mal la pregunta, lo que sucede es que la interfaz o **jFrame**  GestionEmpleados no la cierro ya que me interesa que se mantenga abierta, por lo tanto abro otro **jFrame** AgregarEmpleado se abre y al dar clic en **Agregar** se cierra y deberia actualizar GestionEmpleados

Comment: Probe lo que me menciona en su respuesta pero me abre otro **jFrame** de GestionEmpleado

Comment: Edite ya mi pregunta y de nuevo disculpas..

Comment: modifiqué también la respuesta.

Comment: Me funciono a la perfección, Ahora solo para tener una mejor comprensión y saber como utilizar en el futuro casos por el estilo. Cuando quiera realizar cualquier modificación o acción sin cerrar una interfaz tengo que crear un método static y atributo static ? como funciona la utilización de un método static?

Comment: Creo que sería mejor para ti googelear "que es un método estático
en java", porque la descripción no es sencilla y es algo
muy importante entender si quieres seguir programando.
En la implementación que muestras lo ideal sería manejar
eventos, O sea que una interfraz genere eventos y la otra
interfaz escuche eventos y se actualice. Ese es el esquema
ideal para componentes javax.swing. El tema es muy extenso
te sugiero leer y aprender. Vale la pena si te interesa
progresar en esto. Saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.. veré la manera de utilizar los eventos, para manejar bien esto e investigare mas sobre todo el tema de los métodos astáticos